# cPanel login from WordPress

Tags: plugins

Do I need a cPanel login username and password to go to cPanel from WordPress or only WordPress login is enough to go to cPanel through cPanel Manager (from WORPIT)?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly access the  database  of WordPress with plugin [Portable phpmyadmin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/portable-phpmyadmin/)  and  [Adminer](http://wordpress.org/plugins/adminer/). You only need to login to WordPress dashboard and you will be able to access this.